# Keep Docker running Azure CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a release pipeline with 2 steps, the first one copies a .jar file into a server through SSH, the second step runs a shell script with the following commands:

1. docker container stop $(sudo docker ps -aqf "name=crmbackend")
2. docker rm crmbackend
3. cd /home/artotor/crmbackend
4. docker build -t crmbackend .
5. **docker run -d --name crmbackend -p 9090:8888 crmbackend:latest &**
6. exit 0

And this is the stage in azure devops:

[image: execute deply.sh]

What i am trying to achieve is to keep running the docker (step 5) without killing it, and also tell the pipeline that everything went ok. What could be the way to achieve it?, i've tried to add the options -t -i to docker run without success.

This is the Dockerfile that i am using:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD target/crm-backend.jar crm-backend.jar
EXPOSE 8888
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "crm-backend.jar"]
```

Comment: why not run the container not in your pipeline but in a real container environment?

Comment: can you share your dockerfile? I assume the java app exits, at that point the docker will stop. If you want to keep the container running, the app needs to keep running